# Getting a 400 status bad request while registering a new user

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, redux

I am devloping a webapp with nodejs and reactjs with redux. I am trying to make a request to register a new user but i am getting a bad request.

This is the error i am getting:

POST http://localhost:5000/api/users 400 bad request

This is my users route:

```
const express = require('express');
const config = require('config');
const router = express.Router();
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { check , validationResult } = require('express-validator/');
const User = require('../../models/User');

//@route   POST api/users
//@desc    Register user
//@access  public

router.post('/', [
    check('name', 'Name is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Plese include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check('password', 'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters').isLength({min:6})
], 
async (req, res)=> {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors:errors.array()}); //400 is for bad requests
    }


    const { name, email, password } = req.body;

    try{
        //See if user exists

        let user = await User.findOne({ email });

        if(user){
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg:'User already exists' }] });
        }
    
        //Get users gravatar

        const avatar = gravatar.url(email,{
            s:'200',
            r:'pg',
            d:'mm'
        })

        user = new User({
            name,
            email,
            avatar,
            password
        });
    
        //Encrypt password

        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

        await user.save();
    
        //Return jsonwebtoken -> this for users to be logged in right after registration

        const payload = {
            user:{
                id: user.id
            }
        }

        jwt.sign(
            payload,
            config.get('jwtSecret'),
            {expiresIn: 360000}, //change to 3600 for production
            (err, token)=>{
                if(err) throw err;
                res.json({ token });
            }
            )

    }catch(err){
        console.error('err.message');
        res.status(500).send('Server Error');
    }
    

});

module.exports = router;
```

The route is not the problem i think because if i register manually a user via postman it works.

This is my register.js component:

```
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { connect } from 'react-redux';
    import { Link, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
    import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert';
    import { register } from '../../actions/auth'; 
    import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
    
    const Register = ({ setAlert, register  }) => {
      const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: ''
      });
    
      const { name, email, password, password2 } = formData;
    
      const onChange = (e) =>
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    
      const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (password !== password2) {
          setAlert('Passwords do not match', 'danger');
        } else {
          register({ name, email, password }); 
          console.log('SUCCESS')
        }
      };
    
      
    
      return (
        <section className="container">
          <h1 className="large text-primary">Sign Up</h1>
          <p className="lead">
            <i className="fas fa-user" /> Create Your Account
          </p>
          <form className="form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Name"
                name="name"
                value={name}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Email Address"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
              <small className="form-text">
                This site uses Gravatar so if you want a profile image, use a
                Gravatar email
              </small>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Password"
                name="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
              <input
                type="password"
                placeholder="Confirm Password"
                name="password2"
                value={password2}
                onChange={onChange}
              />
            </div>
            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-primary" value="Register" />
          </form>
          <p className="my-1">
            Already have an account? <Link to="/login">Sign In</Link>
          </p>
        </section>
      );
    };
    
    Register.propTypes = {
      setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      register: PropTypes.func.isRequired
      
    };
    
    
    export default connect( null, {  setAlert , register })(Register);
```

and this is one of my actions auth.js where i request my api

```
import axios from "axios";
import { setAlert } from './alert'
import {
    REGISTER_SUCCESS,
    REGISTER_FAIL
} from './types'

//Register user

export const register = ( { name, email, password } ) => async dispatch => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Content-type': 'application/json'
        }
    }

    const body = JSON.stringify({ name , email, password });

    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/api/users', body, config);

        dispatch({
            type: REGISTER_SUCCESS,
            payload: res.data
        });

    } catch (error) {

        const errors = error.response.data.errors;

        if(errors){
            errors.forEach(error => dispatch(setAlert(error.msg, 'danger')));
        }

        dispatch({
            type:REGISTER_FAIL
        });
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure this might be an axios error on how i am trying to perform a request or a redux mistake.

My app works fine, if i don´t enter or enter invalid data to my registration form all my validation alerts show up. The issue is when i submit the form and try to send the data to register the new user.

Comment: In your developer tools, under the network tab (enable recording) when you submit the form there will be a network request POSTing to your server, can you show the contents of the request?

Comment: You send 400s explicitly from your server code. Have you tried putting logs before each one?

Comment: Btw 429 is probably the code you want for an existing user conflict. And maybe a 422 for validation errors. It will help differentiate too.